# How do I bind a WPF ListView to a property of each element in a list?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, itemssource

I have the following binding on my ListView, which works fine:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}" Margin="5" Name="FiltersList" Height="100"/>
```

Filters is actually a type of `List<LogFilter>`. LogFilters have a property on them called Title. I would like to show the Title of each element in the Filters list in my ListView instead. Is this possible? Something like `ItemsSource="{Binding Filters.Title}"`?

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `ItemTemplate` to display the title:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: I wish I could accept both your answers, since both are great.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you don't need to use `ListView` at all. For your needs `ListBox` with [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be enough:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}" DisplayMemberPath="Title"/>
```

Comment: I wish I could accept both your answers, since both are great.